# Using vlookup when data is in tabular format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I want to bring the amount using an excel funcation.it seems vlookup is not possible as database has columns too.I tried searching online,but in vain as I am unable to put my issue in google search.

Can someone please suggest a an excel formula which can be used in such a scenario.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use VLOOKUP, but then you use the MATCH function to determine the column argument within VLOOKUP

```
=VLOOKUP(A14,$A$2:$G$8,MATCH(B14,$A$2:$G$2,0),FALSE)
```

With your table in A2:G8; Account code in A14; Location in B14

Answer (score 2):

For the tabular data. it is always preferable that you use INDEX - MATCH function. Check the below formula :

```
=INDEX(B$2:$G$7,MATCH(B11,A$2:$A$7,0),MATCH(C11,B$1:$G$1,0))
```

Where,

```
B2:G7 -> Amount Data
A2:A7 -> Account codes
B1:G1 -> Location codes
B11 -> Account code to be searched
C11 -> Location to be searched
```